# Why is the properties imported by 'source' acting so weird and how to avoid this?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo

I met a weird problem when I tried to "echo" something in my shell. I got a config file and a shell:

foo.config:

```
mypath="/home/my/path"
```

bar.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source foo.config
echo "${mypath}ABC"
```

I expect the result to be

```
/home/my/pathABC
```

but it turns out to be

```
ABCme/my/path
```

Yes, seems the chars after the variable $path is rewriting the line. Or say, ${mypath} resets the printer's pointer to the beginning of the line.

Of course, if I copy the declaration of mypath to bash file instead of using source, everything will be fine.

I tested on Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu 18.04 and Rocky 8.4.

Could anyone explain why the variables imported by "source" will act like this, and how to avoid the rewriting to get the "expected result"?

Comment: Not reproducible on `5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS).

Comment: Your `foo.config` file has DOS line endings. Use the `dos2unix` utility on this file (or other alternative methods) and try again.

Comment: Looks like `foo.config` file is using CRLF instead LF

Comment: Thanks, it works now. The foo.config uses CRLF, when I change it to LF, everything goes normal now.